# creating a google doc file in a specific folder

Tags: google-docs, google-slides, file-move

I create a google doc file and populate it from a presentation's notes. However, it puts the file in my root directory and not the directory of the presentation which is in a shared drive folder. I tired to move it but that did not work. Is there a way to create the document in the same folder as the slides? I have the folder ID. The code that I use to create it is:

```
`your text`    let docname = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getName();
`your text`    let doc = DocumentApp.create("Slide Notes - " + docname);
`your text`    let body = doc.getBody();
```

I then put the notes from each slide into body

I tried moving it but it did not move.
addfile and removefile no longer works

Comment: By guessing your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: No longer need help. I used: let doc = DocumentApp.create("5COPY" + "Slide Notes - " + docname);
    DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).moveTo(parent);/

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `No longer need help. I used: let doc = DocumentApp.create("5COPY" + "Slide Notes - " + docname); DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).moveTo(parent);/`, it seems that you used my sample script 1. In that case, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question on a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a new Google Document in the same folder of the parent folder of the active Presentation.
- The parent folder of the active Presentation is the folder on the shared drive.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```js
const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
const fileId = s.getId();
const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
const parent = file.getParents().next();
let docname = s.getName();
let doc = DocumentApp.create("Slide Notes - " + docname);
DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).moveTo(parent);
let body = doc.getBody();
```

When this script is run, a new Google Document is created in the same folder of the parent folder of the active Presentation.

#### Sample script 2:

As another approach, in this pattern, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API v3 at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
const fileId = s.getId();
const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
const parent = file.getParents().next();
const parentFolderId = parent.getId();

let docname = s.getName();
const { id } = Drive.Files.create({ name: "Slide Notes - " + docname, parents: [parentFolderId], mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
let doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
let body = doc.getBody();
```

#### References:

- [moveTo(destination) of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#moveTo(Folder))
- [Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)